# Can't install DOMDocument on Ubuntu 14 with PHP 7

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2, php-7.0

I've recently upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04.1 server from PHP 5.5.x to PHP 7 and am receiving an error within WordPress that says

> WP Google Maps: This plugin uses the DOMDocument class, which is unavailable on this server. Please contact your host to request they enable this library.

The plugin is irrelevant but when I try to install dom extension `sudo apt-get install php-dom` I receive the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-dom
```

Two things:

1. I'm not sure if that's the correct extension to install
2. During the upgrade I ran `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2` that was suggested by the CLI to include during the upgrade

Here is a link to the php info file if it could help: http://boldoriginal.com/info.php

Comment: `DomDocument` is part of the [XML package](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php), so try `php-xml`. If that doesn't work, try `sudo apt-cache search php | grep xml` to find the right name of the package

Comment: Running `php-xml` produced the same error and `grep xml` lists packages, but I'm not sure which one to install; the list is too long to paste here.

Comment: Try looking for one that has the same version of your PHP, so `php7.0-xml`

Comment: Nothing like that is listed:
`libsmokeqtxml4-3 - Qt Xml SMOKE library
libsmokeqtxmlpatterns4-3 - Qt XmlPatterns SMOKE library
php5-xmlrpc
php-horde-xml-element
php-horde-xml-wbxml
php-xml-dtd
php-xml-htmlsax3
php-xml-parser
php-xml-rpc
php-xml-rpc2
php-xml-rss
php-xml-serializer
wulflogger
xmlsysd`

Comment: I actually can't install any package so I'm thinking there's a larger issue. For example, I also can't installe `sudo apt-get install php-curl`